# How to call macro after Refresh or Refresh All button pressed?

Tags: excel, vba

Ultimately, I would like to run a macro after anyone refreshes the workbook, specifically using the Refresh button under the Data tab in Excel.

For the time being, I would be satisfied just getting the BeforeRefresh or AfterRefresh QueryTable events to fire upon pressing the Refresh button.

In addition to the documentation on the Microsoft Dev Center website, the relevant posts I have read include:

- [Excel VBA - QueryTable AfterRefresh function not being called after Refresh completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136069/excel-vba-querytable-afterrefresh-function-not-being-called-after-refresh-comp)
- [VBA For Excel AfterRefresh Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667035/vba-for-excel-afterrefresh-event)
- There are other posts but I lack the reputation to post them.

Here is what I have:

Under Class Modules (qtclass)

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qt As Excel.QueryTable

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    MsgBox "qt_AfterRefresh called sucessfully."
    If Success = True Then
        Call Module2.SlicePivTbl
        MsgBox "If called succesfully."
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "qt_BeforeRefresh called."
End Sub
```

Under the ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim qtevent As qtclass
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Set qt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data-Fund").ListObjects(1).QueryTable
    Set qtevent = New qtclass

End Sub
```

I have tried variations of the second code block under specific worksheets as well, but have yet to find anything that works. Do I need to somehow dim the QueryTable in question in the Worksheet module?

Comment: I usually use *PivotTableUpdate Event* in a dummy *Pivot Table* set up in a dummy hidden sheet to fire up a macro when a user presses the *Refresh All* button. As for your question, I think you better off putting the `WithEvents` line in *ThisWorkbook* (what you call workbook module) and then fire the event there.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion--hadn't really thought of that. It's a bit of a workaround and, to be honest, I fiddled with the PivotTableUpdate event a bit but found it problematic for my use case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You haven't actually connected the querytable to the class instance. 
Revised qtclass

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents qt As Excel.QueryTable
Public Property Set HookedTable(q As Excel.QueryTable)
    Set qt = q
End Property

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    MsgBox "qt_AfterRefresh called sucessfully."
    If Success = True Then
        Call Module2.SlicePivTbl
        MsgBox "If called succesfully."
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "qt_BeforeRefresh called."
End Sub
```

New ThisWorkbook code:

```
Dim qtevent As qtclass
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set qtevent = New qtclass
    Set qtevent.HookedTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data-Fund").ListObjects(1).QueryTable

End Sub
```

Note that this is quite closely coupled. It would be more re-usable if you were to raise events in the class and declare your qtevent variable WithEvents.

Comment: You are a freaking hero, thank you. Both linking the QueryTable to the class and moving the Dim qtevent As qtClass outside of the procedure were the critical bits I was missing.

I'll have a look into your suggestion (now that it finally works). Thanks a lot for the concise but crystal clear explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, wow.  This is exactly the answer and yet there are [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040722) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407514) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083668) [on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925403) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667035) [site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136069) that don't come near this simple precision.  Spent two days looking, ended up writing my own [demo](https://github.com/mcw0933/StackOverflowQuestion32974553/tree/master), before I found this. Nice.

Comment: Life saver. This has been so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://www.excelandaccess.com/create-beforeafter-query-update-events/

**Class:**

Class Name = `clsQuery`

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
 If Success Then
  Debug.Print "After ReFresh"
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
 Debug.Print "Before ReFresh"
End Sub
```

**Module:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim colQueries As New Collection

Sub InitializeQueries()

Dim clsQ As clsQuery
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 For Each QT In WS.QueryTables
  Set clsQ = New clsQuery
  Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
  colQueries.Add clsQ
 Next QT
Next WS

End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook.Event:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 
 Call InitializeQueries
 
End Sub
```