How to unload a userform when Power Query refresh completes when workbook is opened
Background
I have an excel workbook with about 5 power queries in it.  They are set to unload data on save and refresh on open. This is set through the power query as I have been told the workbook basics still need to function should the VBA be stripped from the workbook.  However I am still allowed to add niceties that will make the end user experience better when VBA is present and working.
I have created a button that refreshes all the queries for the user and also presents a message while they are updating, unloads when its done, and replaced with a message box stating operation complete.
The code for the manual refresh is as follows:
Private Sub Btn_Refresh_aLL_Click()
'********************************************************************************
'This sub refreshes all data links.  Does the same job as pressing refresh all
'in the data tab of the ribbon.  Set Userform1 Showmodal to False to all code
'to be continued to be processed.
'********************************************************************************
    
    UserForm1.Show
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Unload UserForm1
    MsgBox "Database refresh complete"
    
End Sub

It works absolutely fine now that I have set ShowModal = False.
Problem
I want to display this same userform during Workbook_Open and then have it unload after the refresh is complete.  I have no clue how to determine when that will occur.  With the manual method that refresh command occurs sandwiched between show and unload. There is no command line for the automatic refresh on open to sandwich.
What I have tried
I tossed in a message box in Workbook_Open to see if the Power Query Refresh occurred before or after the Workbook_Open was triggered since Power Query Refresh executes without code.  Unfortunately for me in this case, Workbook_Open executes first and the message box stops the Power Query Refresh from happening.
In my search for information, I came across this question which seems to discuss this issue, but from a refresh call occurring within VBA.  My situation is different potentially as I am dealing with the automatic process that is triggered within Power Query.  The question is also a little dated and based on what I read, it seems interaction between Power Query and VBA has changed.  If the answer to my issue is in that question, it went over my head and I will need it explained to me.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Wait for databases to load." & vbCr _
        & vbCr _
        & "Monitor progress in the bottom" & vbCr _
        & "right corner of the Excel status bar."
End Sub

Question
How to determine when Power Query Refresh, triggered within Power Query, on workbook open is complete so that a userform displayed during Workbook_Open can be unloaded.
Update
All my Power Query have the following properties set:


You have to ensure that all the Power Queries have 'Run as Background Query" switched off - that will ensure that control won't return to the VBA until the refresh has finished

@CHill60 So I show my form at workbook_Open,  How do I trigger the unloading of the form when the refresh is done?

Turn off the auto refresh and put a RefreshAll in the Workbook_Open, just as you have in the form?

@Rory I still need the spreadsheet to function should VBA get stripped.  Only things I am allowed to do with  VBA is add basic niceties.

You may have to loop through your querytables and test if any of them has .Refreshing = True

@Rory Since Workbook_Open happens before the the Refresh on open by Power query happens, how do you automatically trigger the code that would check for .refreshing = True?

You could use Application.Ontime. Alternatively, if they aren't loading to the data model, you can use a class to sink the querytable's AfterRefresh

@Rory I only learned how to use a form instead of msgbox last night.  Two weeks ago I learned that a form has code in addition to the visual object.  I knew there were these things called class but have no freaking clue on how or why to use them.  As for loading into a Data Model, I am currently dumping the information from the query into tables on various worksheets.  Could you demonstrate how AfterRefresh class would work?

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983053/how-to-call-macro-after-refresh-or-refresh-all-button-pressed

Using these two helper subs
Sub SetAllQueriesRefreshOnOpen(Optional setOn As Boolean = False)
'Sets the Refresh on open settings for all queries in the workbook
'setOn = True sets RefreshOnOpen to True
'As default PQ behaviour is to set this on, default behaviour for this function is to turn it off
    
    Dim objConnection As Object
    For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.RefreshOnFileOpen = setOn
    Next
End Sub
Sub SetAllQueriesBackground(Optional setOn As Boolean = False)
'Sets the BackgroundQuery setting for all queries in the workbook
'setOn = True sets BackgroundQuery = True
'As default PQ behaviour is to set this on, default behaviour for this function is to turn it off

    Dim objConnection As Object
    For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = setOn
    Next

End Sub

In your Workbook_Open sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    SetAllQueriesRefreshOnOpen False
    SetAllQueriesBackground False

    UserForm1.Show
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Unload UserForm1

    'This will ensure workbook works if VBA is stripped
    SetAllQueriesRefreshOnOpen True
    SetAllQueriesBackground True

    MsgBox "Database refresh complete"
End Sub

